# What the difference between mongoose.Promise and promisifyAll?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

For the NPM Bluebird Promise library package, there are two ways to implement Mongoose promises. What's the different between these two?

```
let bluebird = require('bluebird');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
bluebird.promisifyAll(mongoose);
```

versus:

```
let bluebird = require('bluebird');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
```

Answer (score 1):

`promisifyAll` converts mongoose's *callback* api to promises automatically in a bluebird specific way. It works for *every* library that returns standard callbacks and uses objects (and not just mongoose) and is written by bluebird.

`mongoose.Promise` is the standard Mongoose way to use promises, it was added *at a later version* and is mongoose specific. It is also slightly slower *hah!* than the bluebird wrapper because of how promisifyAll does not have to use the promise constructor because it is bluebird specific (where `.Promise` works with any promise implementation).

In most scenarios, both should be fine with `.Promise = bluebird` having the advantage of not having to append the `Async` suffix to function names.